How to implement CBC-ECB encryption
So firstly I want to start with stating that this is a learning exercise and I'm not rolling my own encryption system for real world use.
Specifically I am trying to learn about encryption by doing some practical challenges and this is the one I am currently working on.
This challenge involves implementing your own CBC-ECB encryption/decryption algorithms. As I understand things currently to implement CBC-ECB you would take the current block of 16 bytes and the next block of 16 bytes, XOR them and then ECB encrypt the result.
The issue I am having is that whenever I encrypt a 16 byte block with the ECB encryption function below I need to encrypt 32 bytes. No matter how long my input is, in order to get the same length input back out when I decrypt I need to add an additional 16 bytes of padding to the end of the input.
So when I have 16 byte input I will need to also provided 16 bytes of padding. So I will need to store 32 bytes of encrypted output for every 16 bytes of plain text input.
Looking at other solutions to these challenges online it doesn't look like other people are having this problem. It looks like they are getting 16 bytes of encrypted data for 16 bytes of input data (or something is handling this problem for them). Following that the challenge also has a file that should be decryptable with a provided key that from looking at other peoples solutions doesn't seem to have all of the additional padding.
Encryption and Decryption functions:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

typedef enum {
    BLOCK_SIZE_128_BIT      = 128 / 8,
    BLOCK_SIZE_256_BIT      = 256 / 8,
    BLOCK_SIZE_CUSTOM_VALUE = 0 
} paddingBlockSize;

typedef struct {
    void*    dataWithPadding;
    uint64_t dataLengthWithPadding;
    uint8_t  valueOfByteForPadding;
} PKCS7_Padding;  

typedef struct {
    void*    dataWithoutPadding;
    uint64_t dataLengthWithoutPadding;
    uint8_t  valueOfRemovedByteFromData;
} PKCS7_unPadding;

PKCS7_Padding* addPadding(const void* const data, const uint64_t dataLength, const uint8_t BLOCK_SIZE)
{
    if (0 == BLOCK_SIZE)
    {
        puts("ERROR: block size value must be 0 < BLOCK_SIZE < 256");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    PKCS7_Padding* paddingResult = (PKCS7_Padding*) malloc(sizeof(PKCS7_Padding));
    if (NULL == paddingResult)
    {
        perror("problem with PKCS7_Padding* paddingResult");
        exit(-1);
    }

    uint8_t paddingBytesAmount           = BLOCK_SIZE - (dataLength % BLOCK_SIZE);
    paddingResult->valueOfByteForPadding = paddingBytesAmount;
    paddingResult->dataLengthWithPadding = dataLength + paddingBytesAmount; 
    
    uint8_t* dataWithPadding = (uint8_t*) malloc(paddingResult->dataLengthWithPadding);
    if (NULL == paddingResult)
    {
        perror("problem with uint8_t* dataWithPadding");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    memcpy(dataWithPadding, data, dataLength); 
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < paddingBytesAmount; i++)
    {
        dataWithPadding[dataLength + i] = paddingResult->valueOfByteForPadding;
    }
    paddingResult->dataWithPadding = dataWithPadding;

    return paddingResult;
}

PKCS7_unPadding* removePadding(const void* const data, const uint64_t dataLength)
{
    PKCS7_unPadding* unpaddingResult = (PKCS7_unPadding*) malloc(sizeof(PKCS7_unPadding));
    if (NULL == unpaddingResult)
    {
        perror("problem with PKCS7_Padding* unpaddingResult");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    uint8_t paddingBytesAmount                  = *((uint8_t *)data + dataLength - 1);
    unpaddingResult->valueOfRemovedByteFromData = paddingBytesAmount; 
    unpaddingResult->dataLengthWithoutPadding   = dataLength - paddingBytesAmount;

    uint8_t* dataWithoutPadding = (uint8_t*) malloc(unpaddingResult->dataLengthWithoutPadding);
    if (NULL == dataWithoutPadding)
    {
        perror("problem with uint8_t* dataWithoutPadding");
        exit(-1);
    }

    memcpy(dataWithoutPadding, data, unpaddingResult->dataLengthWithoutPadding);   
    unpaddingResult->dataWithoutPadding = dataWithoutPadding;

    return unpaddingResult;
}

void freePaddingResult(PKCS7_Padding* puddingResult)
{
    free(puddingResult->dataWithPadding);
    free(puddingResult);
}

void freeUnPaddingResult(PKCS7_unPadding* unPuddingResult)
{
    free(unPuddingResult->dataWithoutPadding);
    free(unPuddingResult);
}

int ecb_encrypt(unsigned char *plain_bytes, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *cipher_bytes, size_t plain_bytes_len, size_t *cipher_bytes_len) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len = 0;

    /*size_t padded_length = 0;
    if (plain_bytes_len % 16 > 0) {
        padded_length = plain_bytes_len + (16 - (plain_bytes_len % 16));
    } else {
        padded_length = plain_bytes_len + 16;
    }

    PKCS7_Padding *padded   = addPadding(plain_bytes, plain_bytes_len, padded_length);
    unsigned char *padded_message    = padded->dataWithPadding;
    plain_bytes_len = padded->dataLengthWithPadding;*/

    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        return 4;

    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ecb(), NULL, key, NULL))
        return 5;

    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, cipher_bytes, &len, plain_bytes, plain_bytes_len))//
    //if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, cipher_bytes, &len, padded_message, plain_bytes_len))
        return 6;
    *cipher_bytes_len = len;

    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, cipher_bytes + *cipher_bytes_len, &len))
        return 7;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
}

int ecb_decrypt(unsigned char *cipher_bytes, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *plain_bytes, size_t cipher_bytes_len, size_t *plain_bytes_len) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len = 0;

    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        return 4;

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ecb(), NULL, key, NULL))
        return 5;

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plain_bytes, &len, cipher_bytes, cipher_bytes_len))
        return 6;
    *plain_bytes_len = len;

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plain_bytes + *plain_bytes_len, &len))
        return 7;
    
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    unsigned char plain_text[] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC";
    unsigned char key[]        = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
    unsigned char cipher_bytes[strlen(plain_text)];
    size_t cipher_bytes_len = strlen(plain_text);

    ecb_encrypt(plain_text, key, (unsigned char *) &cipher_bytes, cipher_bytes_len, &cipher_bytes_len);

    size_t plain_bytes_len = 0;
    unsigned char plain_bytes[cipher_bytes_len];

    ecb_decrypt(cipher_bytes, key, (unsigned char *) &plain_bytes, cipher_bytes_len, &plain_bytes_len);

    printf("plain_bytes_len = %lu\n", plain_bytes_len);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < plain_bytes_len; i++){
        printf("%c", plain_bytes[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
       
    return 0;
}

This should compile as is using gcc main.c -lcrypto with gcc. If you run the code as is you will not receive the C's from the plaintext when decrypting. If you uncomment the padding section in ecb_encrypt and change plain_bytes to padded_bytes in the call to EVP_EncryptUpdate you will see that the decryption occurs as expected getting the full plaintext back AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC.
I feel like there is something about how I am handling padding that is incorrect and causing these problems but I am not sure where I should start looking to diagnose the issue.
To add some context here I did not write the padding code, it's from a library I found online and I copied it into the code here to make it easier for anyone trying to recreate the issue.

Adding EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx,false); to the encrypt and decrypt functions removed the padding issues.

Without studying the code (too much...), it seems you have grasped correctly the situation concerning padding.
When using a block cipher in CBC mode, the output by definition will be a multiple of the block size, which also means the decrypted data will need to be a multiple of the block size, in this case 16, 32, 48, ... bytes etc.
The input needs to be filled/padded with something, since you need to input a full block always, that's the padding. After decryption you need some mechanism to determine the actual length of the plain text.
This can be part of the actual plaintext, for example a length field, or if you know it's an ASCII text string, it can be a nul-byte which is a common mechanism to indicate the end of a string. Other terminators are also possible, or basically any scheme you can think of that will let you determine the length or the end of the actual data, when rounded up to the block size. It can also be implicit, perhaps you know that the input data is always an even multiple of the block size.
Since you anyway need padding every time the input is not an even multiple of the block size, some simple schemes to use those extra bytes have been thought up.
PKCS #7 that your code seems to use for it's additional level of padding, works by filling out the extra bytes with a byte value indicating the number of extra bytes. So, if you're encrypting 17 bytes, you'll fill the last 15 bytes of the last block with the byte value 15 for example.
All this being said, I might be missing something, but the following seems questionable:
unsigned char cipher_bytes[strlen(plain_text)]
The cipher_bytes buffer must always be rounded upwards to an even multiple of the block size. So this also seems wrong:
size_t cipher_bytes_len = strlen(plain_text);
Causing you to pass in a too short buffer to the actual encryption. This is probably what's causing the truncation.
When you're doing your extra level of padding (the library does padding by default...) you're probably compensating for this - I haven't analyzed the code in detail, but it seems reasonable.
Start by trying to fix the above.
